# Reactjs issue with Home component

Tags: reactjs

**P.S : I'm new with react**

I ran into an issue in my routing where I have a component called Home sitting in `components/Home/Home.js`

and I have imported everything on the app.js has the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and have my routes as follow

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/Contact" component={Contact}/>
```

And home is a basic stateless component

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

My issue is that my App is Failing to compile unless I change my home import name to something like Home_ or Home.js, as long as the import name is not Home, it is working!

the error says

```
Failed to compile

./src/components/Home/Home
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'mydevpath/src/components/Home/Home'
```

Can someone explain to me why is that happening or if I'm missing something?

Comment: it can be helpful if you add the code for the Home component

Comment: Home is a basic stateless component @obiwankenoobi

Comment: I must say.. it is a weird issue. It really shouldn't matter what you name it because you `export default` the component so any name should work... weird for sure

Comment: FYI Webpack default assumes an entry module of `index.js`, so you can just name it such and import by folder, e.g. `components/Home`. Not an answer to the question but that might be a less awkward folder structure.

Comment: The issue might be in your webpack config. Might want to post your `resolve` object (and maybe even your modules.rules array that applies to `js` files.) Does your `resolve.extensions` look something like `['*', '.js', '.json']`? (and optionally `.jsx` if you're ever using that file naming method).

Comment: @SamVK not really sure where to find those

Comment: Do you have a `webpack.config.js` file? (Or is there some known starter kit this is build off of?)

Comment: My webpack module does not have such file, Project started from scratch with `create-react-app` @SamVK

Comment: Hmm then that should definitely all be correct (if you're ever curious, you can see `create-react-app`'s weback config [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js))